# send html content as function parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I want  to send html content as function parameter.
this is my code:

```
    while($proj=mysqli_fetch_array($projQryResult)){
    $content=$proj['description'];
    echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>$c<form action='insert.php' method='post' id='proj$c' class='formSubmit'><input form='proj$c' type='hidden' value='$proj[id]' name='id'/></td>
                    <td><span style='width:250px; height: 30px;line-height: 35px ; font-family: W_yekan serif; font-size:14px; text-indent: 3px' > $proj[projname]</span></td>
                    <td><i onclick=\"editProj($content)\" class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='edit '></i></td>

            ";

}
?>

function editProj(desc){

CKEDITOR.instances.editorProject.setData(desc);


}
```

$content contais something like this:

```
<p dir="rtl">text</p>
```

it mixes with other my input attributes

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You can always send html as a string without issue?

Comment: the problem was html special characters. I have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it :

```
 $content=addslashes($proj['description']);
    $content=str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$content);
```